# how to fetch data from one table and insert into another table in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $m        = "arushi";
    $em       = "SELECT emailid FROM tblregister WHERE name='$m'";
    $q        = mysql_query($em);
    $n        = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
    $fullName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $address  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $mobNo    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dinner']);
    $summary  = "jsf";
    $sql      = "INSERT INTO tbljcustomer VALUES('$m', '$n', '$fullName',     
    '$address','$mobNo', '$summary')";

    if(!(mysql_query($sql)))
    {
        echo "Sorry!!! we were unable to process please try again";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "customized";
    }
?>
```

on executing this everything works fine except that it doesn't fetch emailid from tblregister rather it displays just Array or sometimes resource id#10. Thanks in advance

Comment: what does print_r($n) show in your screen?

Comment: @LucPrevoo it shows the emailid.. thanks.. anyways $n['emailid'] did the job.. thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
$n=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$emailid = $n['emailid'];
```

and your query will change to

```
$sql="insert into tbljcustomer values('$m', '$emailid', '$fullName','$address','$mobNo', '$summary')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use : `$n['emailid']`

Answer (score 0):

$n is an associative array. Look at the documentation for [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). Use `var_dump($n);` if you want to see the structure of the array. From the documentation:

> mysql_fetch_assoc returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to
>   the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) return an array
try:

```
insert into tbljcustomer values('$m', '".$n['emailid']."', '$fullName',...
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$n
```

with

```
$n['emailid']
```

in your insert query

Answer (score 0):

it will be

```
$email = $n['emailid'];

$sql="insert into tbljcustomer values('$m', '$email', '$fullName',     
'$address','$mobNo', '$summary')";
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$sql      = "INSERT INTO tbljcustomer VALUES('$m', '$n', '$fullName',     
'$address','$mobNo', '$summary')";
```

with

```
$sql      = "INSERT INTO tbljcustomer VALUES('$m', '".$n['emailid']."', '$fullName',     
'$address','$mobNo', '$summary')";
```